# Automate raster polygon area extraction from GeoTIFF files

Tags: shapefile, geotiff-tiff, google-earth-engine, google

I am trying to automate the extraction of all bands from single multipolygon into separate single raster file containing all bands of a single polygon. The GeoTIFF file is exported from Google Earth Engine API (landsat8).

```js
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon([[[37.24154695,  8.01665693],
                                     [37.26876315,  8.01665693],
                                     [37.26876315,  8.04378808],
                                     [37.24154695 , 8.04378808],
                                     [37.24154695,  8.01665693]],
                                     [[37.34154695,  8.11665693],
                                      [37.36876315,  8.11665693],
                                      [37.36876315,  8.14378808],
                                      [37.34154695 , 8.14378808],
                                      [37.34154695,  8.11665693]]]);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                .filterBounds(geometry)
                .filterDate('2016-01-01', '2016-12-31')

var images = dataset.reduce(ee.Reducer.median());

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: images.clip(geometry),
  folder: "test",
  description: 'imageToCOGeoTiffExample2',
  scale: 30,
  region: geometry,
  fileFormat: 'geotiff',
  skipEmptyTiles: true
});
```

I know that it is possible to achieve that with QGIS manually by selecting each polygon manually. But since I have a large amount of single polygons to extract, this method is not viable.

The picture simply depicts a raster file containing 13 bands and two polygons. It is a simple GeoTIFF file but in practice this file contains hundreds of polygons like that. The result would be two separate GeoTIFF files each one describing a polygon area from the input GeoTIFF file and thus the 13 bands for this polygon area.
[image]

Thus I would like to know if it is possible to achieve that task or if it is not.

Note: I am not a specialist of GeoTIFF files thus probably there are some tools or methodologies that I do not know to manage these type of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and quite simple using `gdal_polygonize.py`. Check the [gdal_polygonize.py](https://www.gdal.org/gdal_polygonize.html) documentation.

I've converted you image with success with:

```
gdal_polygonize.py geotiff.tiff -f "ESRI Shapefile" poly.shp
```

The result was:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but with this approach I can just retrieve the polygon shape is I read correctly the doc. What I want is to retrieve all bands from my initial geotiff file and generate a separate geotiff file containing them for each polygon shape depicted in the original file. Note I edited my question since it was not clear enough.

Comment: After you get all the small polygons, you can use each one to cut the original raster image (you can use `gdalwarp -cutline`). You need a small script to iterate through all polygons.

Comment: I seems that I am doing something wrong or the file generated by `gee` is not formatted in the same way. When I am applying `gdal_polygonize.py` I obtain the shapefile. I open this shapefile in qgis to see the result. It seems that shapes have been correctly detected. Then I am trying to obtain each polygon by iterating the shapefile with `fiona` but I have much more lines. Thus I suppose it is not the correct way to obtain each polygon from a shapefile...

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found another solution to extract my rasters described by polygons more easily and which seems to be faster. Since, I know in advance all polygons that are in the original raster (because they are used to build this raster). I can reuse these coordinates for single polygon extraction. To achieve that I wrote the following Python script to extract the first polygon (To extract several polygons I just need to iterate the process).

first polygon is defined as a list:

```
poly = [[37.24154695,  8.01665693],
        [37.26876315,  8.01665693],
        [37.26876315,  8.04378808],
        [37.24154695 , 8.04378808],
        [37.24154695,  8.01665693]]
```

from this `poly` I extract the first and the third line that correspond to `xmin ymin xmax ymax`

```
from subprocess import call
call('gdalwarp -te 37.24154695 8.01665693 37.26876315 8.04378808 imageToCOGeoTiffExample3.tif  test2.tif', shell=True)
```

I think it would be better if I can directly pass to `gdalwrap` the `poly` object that  corresponds to geo-referenced coordinates of the polygon instead of retrieving the the min and max but I did not find the corresponding option in the `gdalwrap` doc. Moreover, with the approach that I use, It only works with squares and rectangles shapes.